# How do I make this type of layout with CSS?

Tags: css, layout

It's a type of layout that has fixed lengths at the edges, but the main content container is fluid.

I made a jsfiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/JyXtR/3/
I just can't get it and I don't understand why.

What I want to get is this
https://i.stack.imgur.com/j7hpS.png

The main content, and content on the right's containers should be the same height regardless of how much content is in them.

Am I really bad at this or is CSS not suited for these types of layouts where they take up an entire page at all times?

Comment: Do you mean something like http://jsfiddle.net/22D4F/2/?

Comment: Something like that, but not exactly that. Ideally, main content and the sidebar should have their own scroll bars since content height can differ on both. I do like the way you bordered the sidebar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/22D4F/3/). Use `display:inline-block;`, and adjust the width of both objects. I manually set the height of the main div to 300px for presentation purpose. Note that your inner objects have to use less `than height:100%`, since main won't scroll.

Maybe it's possible to set a height attribute to a `display:table-cell` element, but the given solution should work in your case.

Update: http://jsfiddle.net/22D4F/4/

Comment: Cool. Any way to make the height of main to be 100% minus the footer height? Or will I have to do that with Javascript? And why does the sidebar stick to the bottom of #main when #main is bigger?

Comment: I can't reproduce the second bug, but you can adjust the 100% minus footer height by using positioning. However, the current solution is quite a mess, maybe you'll find a better one (hint: put together what belongs together, use as little css as needed) ;).

Comment: The updated solution works great. :) Thanks for all the help. This was really stressing me today.

Answer (score 0):

Check it now. But there is one problem, because it cannot be solved only with css.
The problem is layout not work properly if sidebar is longer then content. It cannot be solved without javascript, so YOU MUST SET min-height of content div to sidebar content height. 
http://jsfiddle.net/DvaWk/

Answer (score 0):

You need to 'float:left' your chat div and set the online users div to 200px;
EDIT: Also add overflow:auto to #main.

Comment: This doesn't seem to do it. Take note that both divs have `position: absolute` because they're not supposed to be scrolled. Only the content should be scrolled.

Comment: @DeaDEnD - Not in your jsfiddle it doesnt. Note my edit above.

Comment: you're right they have relative. Sorry I've been trying this with many types of positions I got confused.

Comment: @DeaDEnD Edited my post above.